# Clarification on JAVA Annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I tried to understand the purpose of annotations but was not able to get the clear idea.
The below mentioned quote was copied from the book **"Java Persistence With Hibernate ".**

> If you’re worried that the import of the JPA interfaces will bind your
>   code to this package, you should know that it’s only required on your
>   class-path when the annotations are used by Hibernate at runtime. You
>   can load and execute this class without the JPA interfaces on your
>   classpath as long as you don’t want to load and store instances with
>   Hibernate.

Can anyone pls explain why the annotations are not binding the class to specific package ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use classes that are annotated with JPA annotations in an application that doesn't have JPA in its classpath. That's what it means. Annotations are just metadata, and the JVM doesn't care if the classes of the annotations are not available at runtime.